# c++11 template specialisation wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, wrapper, template-specialization

I want to do something like this in c++11 but i dunno how to do or what to google:
the goal of this is to emulate polymorphism on return type here is a sample of code to explain what I want to do

```
enum foo : int
{
    bar = 1,
    baz = 2
};

class Common
{
public:
    Common(){}
    ~Common(){}
    foo _val;
};

class A : public Common
{
    A() :_val(foo::bar){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    int func(){return 0;}
};

class B : public Common
{
    B() :_val(foo::baz){}
    ~B(){}
    double func(){return 60.55;}
};

template <foo V>
auto wrapper(Common * val)
{
    return wrapper<V>(val);
}
template <foo::bar>
A * wrapper(Common * val)
{
    return (A*)val;
}

template <foo::baz>
A * wrapper(Common * val)
{
    return (B*)val;
}

void leFunc(Common * t)
{
    auto val = wrapper<t::_val>(&t)->func();
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Common *> lst = {new A, new B};
    for (auto & e : lst)
        leFunc(e);
}
```

edit:
some real example of what i want to do:
the idea is to have calls like this:

```
int i = wrapper<1>(myInterface &);
double k = wrapper<2>(myInterface &);
std::list<float> i = wrapper<3>(myInterface &);
```

with the template specialisation stored in the interface (the value)
Edit code to be more precise

Comment: Okay I see, so you just want to kind of map say 0->ints , 1->doubles, and so on. That way you pass in a value to the wrapper and it returns a different return value? Can you just use boost::any as a return type for a virtual funtion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want. Maybe something like [this](http://codepad.org/tt9RdB17). Below is the src.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


enum Gender{
  MALE = 1, FEMALE = 2, UNKNOWN = 3
};


template <Gender genderValue>
struct CommonPerson{
 virtual Gender getGender()const{ return genderValue; }
 virtual ~CommonPerson(){};
};

struct Male: public CommonPerson<MALE>{};
struct Female: public CommonPerson<FEMALE>{};

string toString(const Gender& g){ 
 if(g == MALE) return "MALE";
 else return "FEMALE";
}
template<typename T>
void printGender(const T& person){
 std::cout << toString(person.getGender()) << endl;
}
int main(){
 Male male;
 Female female;  
 printGender(male);
 printGender(female);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah something like that thanks im testing this solution.
i edited my post to be more explicit of what i want to do